# InvokeMember in c# with "reflected" parameters

Tags: c#, reflection, parameters, invoke

I want to call a method of a DLL via reflection (can't be sure that the other dll is loaded) but have problems with the parameters.

The method I want to call is

```
public void Add(DBTable table, String sField, DBValue value, SQLConditionType type)
```

in [the MP-TVSeries project](http://code.google.com/p/mptvseries/source/browse/trunk/MP-TVSeries/DataBase/SQLCondition.cs)

What I tried is this:

```
        // WindowPlugins.GUITVSeries
        Assembly MPTVSeries = Assembly.Load("MP-TVSeries");
        Type sqlConditionType = MPTVSeries.GetType("WindowPlugins.GUITVSeries.SQLCondition");
        Type sqlConditionTypeEnumType = MPTVSeries.GetType("WindowPlugins.GUITVSeries.SQLConditionType");
        Type dbEpisode = MPTVSeries.GetType("WindowPlugins.GUITVSeries.DBEpisode");

        // SQLCondition sql = new SQLCondition();
        object sql = Activator.CreateInstance(sqlConditionType);

        // sql.Add(new DBEpisode(), DBEpisode.cFilename, filename, SQLConditionType.Equal);
        sqlConditionType.InvokeMember("Add",
        BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
        null,
        sql,
        new object[] { 
            Activator.CreateInstance(dbEpisode),
            dbEpisode.GetField("cFilename"),
            filename,
            sqlConditionTypeEnumType.GetField("Equal")
        });
```

but this throws an exception with the message

> The method "WindowPlugins.GUITVSeries.SQLCondition.Add"
>   could not be found.

My guess is that I am doing something wrong with the parameters, but as I am totally new to reflection I can't get my head around it.

Someone please help ;-)

Comment: Is there more than one `Add` method? Is `Add` defined on on a class that SQLCondition inherits from?

Comment: No there is only one Add method and SQLCondition is not inherited. I will try to follow Hans' suggestion and take a step back ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going too fast.  Get sqlConditionType.GetMethod() working first to get a MethodInfo so you can be sure this is not a method overload resolution problem.  The arguments you pass are smelly, particularly *filename* and *sqlConditionTypeEnumType.GetField("Equal")*.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, I will try and see what GetMethod() tells me. "filename" is just a string but sqlConditionTypeEnumType.GetField("Equal") is smelly, I agree.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Hans. GetMethod().Invoke() throws more detailed exceptions and helped me to locate all problems. I had to use GetValue(null) on the fields and instantiate a new DBValue object with the filename string.